# google analytic code appears in the website

Tags: html

Hello am new to google analytics and I want to track my website, I followed all the steps and got a measure Id which I pasted in head section, but when I access the website in the browser I still see the code , what is wrong
Here is my code

```
<head>
G-2Y6RFWP3ZF
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>ICT specialists</title>
<!-- *****animation link*** -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<!-- *****end of animation link*** -->
<!-- ----slick slider- links------ -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/slick.css">
<!-- ****bootstrap link**** -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- ****end bootstrap link**** -->
<!-- *******social-icons link*** -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- *******end social-icons link*** -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
<!-- *****aos link******************* -->
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-2Y6RFWP3ZF"></script>

<!-- ***css link*** -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
<!-- *****end css link**** -->
<!-- ***icon*** -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/logo/logo.png">
<!-- ***end of icon*** -->
</head>
```

Comment: For some reason you have the ID written right below the `<head>`. It should not be there. There should be no text directly inside the `<head>` element, only some allowed child elements. I suppose you pasted the code snippet from analytics further down in the head?

Answer (score 0):

Line 2:
`G-2Y6RFWP3ZF`
is not inside any tags so will appear as text in the browser. remove this as it is not doing anything.

This line is all you need

`<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-2Y6RFWP3ZF"></script>`